# Strange error message during CentOS 6.5 installation regarding disk containing BIOS RAID metadata?

Tags: centos, system-installation, raid

While attempting to use an old 40GB HDD to setup a kind of junky though usable Athon 1GHz system I ran into the following error during the HDD identification/partitioning phase of the installation:

> Warning: Disk sda contains BIOS RAID metadata, but is not part of any recognized BIOS RAID sets. Ignoring disk sda

How can I work around this issue?

Comment: I would assume that `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=100` or something similar would have worked as well (that nukes the first 100MB of the disk - I don't know where the RAID data is actually kept).

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco - you're probably correct, but it seems better to use actual tools to do this type of work rather than take `dd` to the disk, no?

Comment: Most definitely; that's why mine was a comment not an answer. I was giving a command that I've used in the past to nuke all the partitioning information, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue in the following thread titled: [[SOLVED] CentOS 6 on GA-990FXA-UD5](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7114).

The solution involved removing the BIOS RAID metadata that apparently was part of a residual software RAID that the 40GB HDD must of been used in. Running this command in the CentOS 6.5 LiveCD in a terminal fixed it:

```
$ dmraid -r -E /dev/sda
Do you really want to erase "pdc" ondisk metadata on /dev/sda ? [y/n] :
```

To which I replied "y".

#### Anaconda

This failure is a little unnerving since it occurs while running the Anaconda installer tool that's typically used by all the Redhat products (CentOS/Fedora/RHEL) and the failure is not graceful.

I'm not sure why, but Anaconda cannot deal with this situation itself, and it leaves you in a state where you can see the "verbose" debug output, which was far from helpful.

I saw no other way around the issue from within Anaconda.

Comment: A very small addition: You can run the dmraid command directly from the CentOS 6.5 install media by using `CTRL+ALT+F2` to switch to the anaconda shell tty / terminal. This saves burning a separate LiveCD.

Answer (score 2):

This unsupported pseudoRAID setup causes RHEL6's Anaconda to get stuck during the installation process as well. The workaround is pretty easy, though -- simply adding the `nodmraid` option to the kernel command line allows the installation to carry on.

To make this modification, hit the Tab key when the CD's bootloader menu comes up, and add `nodmraid` as an extra argument. In my opinion it is a bit unfortunate that Anaconda decides to ignore these drives even when explicitly asked to nuke their contents via the `clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=...` stanza.